# Adding the digit "0" to a number in a list field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

I have a custom with a field requiring to put an 8 digits number in it. In some cases when the number starts with a "0"  SharePoint ommits the first "0" and display only the rest, so, a number with only 7 digits.

What I am trying to do is: First verify if the number is a 7 digits length and if so I have to add the digit "0" in front. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to make any mathematical calculations on the column's value, make it a single line of text, and add validation to ensure the character limit and the numeric characters:

```
=AND(LEN(Column)=8;ISNUMBER(Column+0))
```

http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2012/02/sharepoint-2010-create-and-validate-a-number-field-in-a-list-without-thousand-separator/