# How to force a number field to keep zeros at the start?

Tags: 2016, formatting, number

I would like to use a number field to add phone number to a Sharepoint list. But if the phone number starts with 0, it is automaticly removed by default. Is there any way to keep it? I didn't want to use text field to ensure users not enter non number characters.

Comment: A number can't begin with a zero if it's not a decimal number. I would use a single line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding an out-of-the-box 'telephone number' field, `Primary Phone`, to a list, but it is a text field.

So, I found [this other post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100744/adding-the-digit-0-to-a-number-in-a-list-field) which deals with your issue.  It seems there is no very simple solution to this, as Sharepoint automatically disregards a `0` in a number field.

I've added a picture - I'd already created this field, so I think it shows with brackets () instead of square brackets []

[image: create edit field]

Comment: Well I tought so, just hoped maybe there is an easy solution. Thanks for the link. I have bad experience with calculated fields, it can be bugged with low chance so I wanted to avoid using it, but looks like no other way.

Comment: @Nefri, no calculated fields are needed. You must place this formula in `validate column` section on your column edit page.

Comment: I've added a picture to show the screen AlexZh is referring to

Answer (score 0):

Use "Custom" prefix (it has a selection of - (nothing) $, pound sign etc, and then it has a custom option). Set is as 0 and voila, you have a phone number with a 0 before it.

[image]