# 6 digit ID SharePoint workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, string

I currently have a workflow that creates an ID. (Put the actual listitem ID into another field). I put the listitem id into a variable and then apply this variable into my custom column. I am wanted to create IDs with 6 digits ie 000001, 000012, 000111 however I am not sure what string functions I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the answer if there are any string functions. But if there are not you could try a workaround:

IF [%ID] < 10, Set [%ListItemID] to "00000" + [%ID]

ELSE IF [%ID] < 100, Set [%ListItemID] to "0000" + [%ID]

ELSE IF [%ID] < 1000, Set [%ListItemID] to "000" + [%ID]

[...]

Not a nice solution and a bit of a hassle, but it works. You could also add some other prefix or suffix like "IDTYPE-000020-2018"

Comment: The answer from Mike Smith is superior to this "solution" and should be used for padding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the steps for a 2010 style workflow:
(assuming an integer as the data type)

- Add a "Extract Substring from End of String" action.
- Set it to return 6 characters.
- Use the String Builder to concatenate six zeros and - your value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple workflow could SET the custom column value for you.  I've used a '2010 workflow', but it is compatible with Sharepoint 2013 too.  I don't know which version of Sharepoint you are using.

Please reference [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100744/adding-the-digit-0-to-a-number-in-a-list-field) for a calculated column, which seems like it would achieve what you are looking to do.

Create a new workflow>type `set` >you'll see Sharepoint comes up with some automatic suggestions>select `set field in current item`.

[image]

For my example, I'm choosing to set the Title field to the current item's ID.  Substitute Title for your custom column name.

[image]

Once you are happy with the way this works, you may wish to change the workflows Start Options to `Start workflow automatically when an item is created`.  Since you probably only want the value to be set (copied) once.

[image]

Comment: this won't add the zero's

Comment: agree with last point. I have already done this, I need help with string functions and adding the 0s

Comment: Somehow I didn't realise it needed to be 6 digits, sorry about that.  I've updated my answer to include a link to a similar post

Comment: No worries, appreciate the help anyway. Sorry, can't see the link on your answer